# Image Replacement (JS/JQuery) working in IE but not FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have tried multiple solutions for replacing broken images (both JS & jQuery) and all work perfectly with IE but not in FF, is there a reason for this?

Are images handled differently in FF that may cause this?

JQuery Example:

```
$("img").error(function(){
  $(this).unbind("error").attr("src", "nopic.jpg");
});
```

Javascript Example: (triggered by onError event in img tag)

```
function noimage(img){
   img.onerror="";
   img.src="nopic.jpg";
   return true; }
```

Both of these examples work perfectly in IE but not at all in FF. What gives?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have firebug installed? check firebug in firefox and look at what it is complaining about

Comment: In Firefox, go to Tools -> Error Console. See if you find anything relevant. Your code looks fine.

Comment: I have checked the error console and don't see any issues. Any other ideas?

Comment: If it helps, when I right-click on a broken image and view the source, it still is pointing to the original source. The replacement is simply not taking place.

Comment: The code that sets the attr is inside the error function, but the error function is being unbinded from the selector before the attr is set. Does anyone else see this as a potential problem?

Comment: @Nick The error is triggered by the original src being wrong, i.e. pointing at a non-existent file, not by the manual setting of src in the code. The unbind basically just turns off the error handler after the first time it's triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're testing locally, aren't you, by pointing at a file URL?

Try testing on an actual server, even if it's just local. I believe that Firefox relies on the HTTP status code returned from the image GET to trigger an error; if you're loading from a file://... URL there's no server involved, so you don't get the error.

From the [jQuery API docs for `error()`](http://api.jquery.com/error/):

> This event may not be correctly fired when the page is served locally. Since error relies on normal HTTP status codes, it will generally not be triggered if the URL uses the file: protocol.

**EDIT:** As we've discussed in the comments, this appears to be because for some reason your intranet server is not responding to a missing resource with a 404 (or any other error, by the sounds of things.)

Because Firefox doesn't receive an error, it doesn't trigger the error handler, which seems like sane behaviour.

I think your problem just became "my server doesn't return 404 errors for missing content", but you might need to experiment a bit more to gather evidence before asking that one (and possibly ask it on Serverfault rather than on SO...)

Comment: I'm not positive I understand what you mean. All files are housed on our companies intranet server (SharePoint). 
An example URL to an image would be: `http://domain/folder/folder/Online/PublishingImages/images/picture.jpg` 
Are you saying this may be the issue?

Comment: @Sunburnt Nope, clearly my guess was wrong! As long as you've actually got "http://..." starting the URL, then you should be okay.   What do you actually see if you go to `http://domain/folder/folder/Online/PublishingImages/images/some_missing_broken_image.jpg` in Firefox? Do you get a 404 error?

Comment: Thanks for your help! Interestingly enough I get a white page which just has text showing the URL of the broken image. I get a 404 error in IE.

Comment: @Sunburnt Interesting! I wonder if that's significant. Do you get a 404 page if you point at a different server? Some random nonexistent image on the internet, say? Can you look at the server response in the Net tab of Firebug? Does Firebug show a 404 status code?

Comment: @Matt - When I try to open a random non-existent image on the internet I receive the 404 error. But if I type anything with our domain, it opens a blank page with the URL I submitted on it. This probably is the issue. Can you think of any other way to get around this?  When I view the 'Net' tab under any of these circumstances it is blank.

Comment: @Sunburnt If your server won't return a 404 where a file is missing, that's going to be a trifle difficult to work around. It may be worth asking a new question -- maybe on Serverfault? -- to see if you can fix your server's behaviour. It's odd that the Net tab is blank, though. You should at the very least see the GET request being sent by the browser. I've updated my answer as best I can...

Comment: @Matt - Thanks for everything. At least now I don't feel crazy!!

Comment: @Sunburnt No problem. Just to double-check things, try pointing your Firefox at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KHrS4/1/ -- it should have your code in it (set up to run on dom ready) and it should work in Firefox, thus proving that you're not going crazy :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the `error` handler first, **before** setting the src of an image. So setting the src in HTML and then bind it via JavaScript is not working.

You can prove this for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/4Wcnj/2/.

HTML:

```
<img width=500 id=img height=500 src="missing1">
```

JavaScript:

```
// At this point, missing1 is having an error, but no handler set so far

$("#img").error(function() {
    alert("Missing: " + $(this).attr("src"));
});

// The bind handler has been set, now if you set the src wrongly, you
// get the alert
$("img").attr("src", "missing2");
```